# Malfunction for android:color in xml for Android 10

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-10.0

I have a strange problem. I have made ripple_effect.xml which I use in RecyclerView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#4F66FF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Single view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@color/ripple_effect">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_view_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter

```
class AdapterCategory(private val list: List<Category>, private val iOnClickHandler: IonClick, private val context: Context) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterCategory.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

        internal var picture: ImageView

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
            this.picture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_view_category)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            itemView.isEnabled = false
            itemView.postDelayed(Runnable { itemView.isEnabled = true }, 500)
            iOnClickHandler.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.view_category, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val ivImage = holder.picture
        val icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, list[position].image)

        ivImage.setImageDrawable(icon)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    interface IonClick {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }
}
```

I have received few recording from testing devices from Google, and on few models the color #4F66FF is violet. Here is list devices where code works fine:

- Redmi 5 Plus - MIUI 11.0.2
- Motorola XT1650 - Android 7.0 Samsung
- Galaxy S9 G960U1 - Android 8
- Xperia XZ1 G8441 - Android 8
- Nokia 1 FRT -Android 8.1.0
- LG AS110 - Android 6.0.1
- Pixel 3 - Android 9
- P8 Lite - Android 5.0.1
- Pixel - Android 7.1.2

Color is wrong for these devices:

- Redmi Note 8 Pro - MUI 11
- P30 Pro - EMUI 10
- Xiaomi Mi 9t - Android 10
- Pixel 4 - Android 10

Imho as I can see problem is only on Android 10. Why? Any nice solutions to make what I want but in different way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`RippleDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable), which can be styled.... or try 8 digit colors.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.

Comment: Using another name might already help, in case the framework styles override... this color needs to come from somewhere. Even in XML preview, it should be visible, when switching to API 29 or 30 and selecting the according theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:color="@android:color/background_light" android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/background_light" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Ok, so what was missing it was attribute color for item..
Without it violet color is comming from nowhere. I have checked my project few times and I am 100% sure. I keep this topic maybe it will be valuable if not delete it. Cheers.